# Meteor Iron Router Catch-All 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect, meteor, iron-router

I am migrating an app from the website's root domain to a subdomain. The new app on the root domain is written in Meteor and uses iron-router. To avoid breaking external links I want to 301-redirect all URLs not handled by the meteor app to the subdomain.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this with iron-router. Since I am doing a 301-redirect it is a server route (via {where: 'server'}) but when I do this the catchall route takes precedence over all of the other existing routes, even though it is defined further down in my routes file.

Versions:

Meteor 1.0.3.1

iron:router 1.0.7

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
});
Router.route('/about', function () {
  this.render('about');
});

// Takes precedence over all above routes (due to server?)
Router.route('/(.*)', function () {
  this.response.writeHead(301, {'Location': 'https://subdomain.thedomain.com/' + this.params[0]});
  this.response.end();    
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your route pattern is wrong. Please try the pattern below:

```
Router.route('/:path?', function () {
  this.response.writeHead(301, {'Location': 'https://subdomain.thedomain.com/' + this.params.path});
  this.response.end();    
}, {where: 'server'});
```

`?` means the parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a better way to achieve your goal:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers
  .use('/url_to_redirect', function(req, res, next) {
    // 301 Moved Permanently
    res.writeHead(301, {
      'Location': '/url_where_we_want_to_go'
   });
    res.end();
  });
```

For more information about this: http://meteorpedia.com/read/HTTP_Redirects